# How to connect to my web app running on mac over WiFi?

Tags: network, wifi, web-app

I have very recently switched to mac, so i am a bit lost here...

I am running a test web app (Spring Boot app) on my mac now and I need to connect to it over WiFi form another device.

Now, when the app was running on win I could connect on

```
https://192.168.0.106:8080
```

(the IP address of the new mac is 192.168.0.102) but if I go to  https://192.168.0.102:8080 I get only "This page is not available"....

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a few reasons, but your security settings are probably the most likely candidates.

## Temporarily turn Off the Firewall

The easiest way to test this is to (very) temporarily turn off your firewall:

**System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Turn Off Firewall**

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]

Retest your connectivity, if it works, turn your firewall back on and then allow the app through the firewall.

Comment: Thanks Deesbek, the firewall is turned off, but no success :-(((

Comment: open up terminal and do `netstat -na|grep 8080` look for a line like `tcp4       0      0  *.8080                 *.*                    LISTEN     ` if it is not there you need to restart the app, or it is not running.